# customise Donut graph using nvd3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am trying to achieve the transparent color of the area with only borders in spite of color fill for a donut graph. I am using nvd3 with angularJS, but unable to achieve that. Any suggestions on this as how to do this.

If there is any library - which is capable of doing so, please suggest.

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sase4.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I m trying to create a doughnut chart using nvd3 JS and angularJS...I am able to create it. I wanted to customise the color fill to contain only borders and no color. I hv attached the image to show, what I m trying to achieve..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the style set in `nv.d3.css`.

Add this style after including `nv.d3.css`

```
.nvd3.nv-pie path {
stroke: inherit;
stroke-width: 1px;
stroke-opacity: 1;
fill: white;
}
```

If you only want this to apply this to a particular pie chart add the id to the style selector.